# Будь ласка чи будь-ласка?

Tags: граматика

У мене виник спір із подругою про те,  як правильно писати **'Будь ласка'** чи **' будь-ласка'**? Допоможіть  вирішити спір.

Comment: -1: будь ласка, наступним разом здійсніть спроби самостійно знайти відповідь, у тому числі, шукайте наявні запитання на цьому сайті. Більше подробиць тут: [ask] і тут: [faq]

Answer (score 4):

[Мова- ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/orfografiya/bud-laska)

[image]

[СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=46808&page=1478)

> ◇ Будь ла́ска (ласка́вий, рідше ласка́в) <Бу́дьте ласка́ві> див.
>   бу́ти; Запобіга́ти (рідше запопада́ти) ла́ски див. запобіга́ти;
>   Здава́тися / зда́тися на ла́ску див. здава́тися1; Зроби́ (зробі́ть,
>   май, ма́йте) ми́лість (ла́ску) див. зроби́ти; (2) Коли́ [б] (мо́же)
>   твоя́ (ва́ша) ла́ска (рідко ми́лість) – уживається при ввічливому
>   вираженні прохання.
>
> **[(37) Будь ла́ска](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6191&page=226)** (ласка́вий, рідше ласка́в) <Бу́дьте ласка́ві>:
>   а) усталена форма чемного звертання при проханні, запрошенні,
>   пропозиції і т. ін.; прошу